# call controller method in radio button using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am new to ruby on rails. Is it possible to call a controller action inside a radio button.

```
<%= form_tag :action => 'show' do %>
  <strong>Select device: </strong> 
  <br></br>
  <strong>Chose: </strong><%=  radio_button_tag :name,:time, @time, :onclick => "this.parentNode.submit();"%>Time
  <%=  radio_button_tag :name,:graph%>Graph
```

when selecting first radio button I have to go to show method inside the controller.its working properly. Selecting the second radio button I also have to go to another method inside the controller. How it is possible?

Comment: you have to add some javascript that will change the action attribute of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following :

The form will lead to the same action for both radio buttons.

Inside the action, depending on the selected radio, it will call the right action :

```
def show
  if params[:name] == :time
    self.action_for_time
  elsif params[:name] == :graph
    self.action_for_graph
  end
end

protected

def action_for_time
  # ...
end

def action_for_graph
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
<%= radio_button_tag :name,:graph, :onclick => "window.location.href=<YOUR_PATH>" %>Graph
```

you can write(e.g. you wanna go to home page)

```
<%= radio_button_tag :name,:graph, :onclick => "window.location.href=/home/" %>Graph
  # or
<%= radio_button_tag :name,:graph, :onclick => "window.location.href=<%=home_path%>/" %>Graph
```

Comment: onclick => "window.location.href=<YOUR_PATH>" ,In YOUR_PATH can we write the path of controller or function inside controller?

Answer (score 0):

I think a more clean way of doing this would be,

```
<div id="my-select" >
--
<<view code>>
--
</div>
```

application.js

```
$(function() {

   $("#my-select").on("click",function() {
    <<do-what-you-want>>;
   });

});
```

I maybe a little casual about your route and controller but if you like this solution, you will figure it out.